# What is a constructed variety of a natural language called?

Tags: terminology, natural-languages, classification

What would a conlang created to be an alternate version of an already existing natural language be classified as?

For example, a version of English that could have been spoken in an alternate steampunk-era Victorian England, or a conlang of the Finnish language in the year 2349. To be clear, I'm assuming that the conlang would be an actual, dedicated one, and not just a few "alternate" words thrown in for flavor; the examples I picked were just the first ones that came to mind.

(Bonus: is there a classification for a conlang created to be a conlang of a conlang in this same way?)

Comment: Related question on [linguistics.se] calling it **constructed accent**: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14586/we-have-constructed-languages-but-are-there-constructed-accents

Comment: @jknappen Such a conlang would presumably still be mutually intelligible with the source language if it is rightly called an accent. Which would apply to some, but not all, of what is asked about here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be an **a posteriori** conlang, in contrast with an **a priori** one. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language#A_priori_and_a_posteriori_languages). The process of changing a language through time is called **diachronic conlanging**.

An example of a very well-done a posteriori conlang would be [Carisitt](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/69ktl7/redefining_ielangs_introducing_carisitt/) which has been developed as if it was a natural language deriving from [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) (that is, it is also an example of diachronic conlanging). Examples of an a priori conlang are abundant, for instance all of Tolkien’s works.

Comment: [Reference to the Conlang Wikia show that "a posteriori conlang" is definitely a term used by the community](http://conlang.wikia.com/wiki/Category:A_posteriori).

Comment: It certainly is - I’m an active member of multiple conlanging communities. However, I’m not really sure what to link as a reference for the above terms.

Comment: @Adarain I'll wait a little bit to see if any more answers come, though it's a fairly simple question. In the meantime, I suppose links to specific languages that fit the criteria would be good examples/references. Just having the correct terminology helps the most with looking up additional info.

Comment: A posteriori conlang is much more generic than the thing asked for in the question. Essentially all naturalistic conlangs (including Esperanto) are on the a posteriori side.

Comment: I just noticed that wikipedia actually has a section on this topic. Editing in

Comment: @jknappen Esperanto, sure. But “essentially all naturalistic conlangs” is _far_ from correct. Basically every conlang seen in popular media are a priori naturalistic conlangs. For example, Sindarin, Dothraki… An exception would be Trigedasleng in the TV show The 100, which is explicitly derived from English and therefore a posteriori. (also, Esperanto isn’t naturalistic)

Answer (score 5):

For naturalistic languages placed in an [Alternative History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history) setting the term [Altlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_language#Alternative_languages) (short from Alternative Language) is used.

An example of such an Altlang is [Alternese](http://jbr.me.uk/allo.html) (an alternative history English) by Justin B. Rye.

Comment: Oh, very cool. Are all altlangs diachronic conlangs?

Comment: At least all that I am aware of.